# Balls are transferred from one box to another - Markov chains

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider box A, which contains four white and five black balls. Then consider box B, which contains five white and four black balls. Two balls are transferred from box A to box B. What is the probability that a ball drawn from box B is white?

I'm pretty sure this question has to do with transition probabilities and Markov chains, but don't know where to start. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: No need for complicated computations.  Just consider the three possible cases separately:  you add $WW, WB,BB$ to box $B$.

Comment: @lulu So is it right to say: For **WW** it's (4/9)*(3/8)*(7/11)? Because the probability of two white balls in Box A is the first two terms, and the probability of a white ball in box B after the switch is (7/11)? Similarly, would **WB** be (4/9)*(5/8)*(6/11) and **BB** be (5/9)*(4/8)*(5/11)? And then we add these individual probabilities.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @lulu

Comment: You did all the work!  Good luck.

Comment: You may need to consider **BW** too (which will be the same as **WB**)